# iOS: writing raw ethernet packets

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ethernet

I'd like to send (and also listen to) raw Ethernet packets from an iPhone/iPad.
A packet looks like a classic Ethernet II packet:

dest_mac_address | src_mac_address | type | payload | check_sum.

The type is not IP, neither something well-known, which seems to prevent me from using CFStream and CFSocket.

I can do that from MacOS using BPF, associated to the interface "en0". But it seems that BPF is not available on iOS.
There are apps to sniff networks working on iOS, but only if the device is jailbroken.
Has someone ever heard of a solution to this problem, without jailbreaking the device?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You can't write raw ethernet packets without root access (it's a security feature) and you don't have root access on iOS without jailbreaking.

Comment: @Petesh Thank you! That's what I feared...

Comment: Raw ethernet frames use a length (<= 1500) vs. an EtherType field, and the payload starts with `0xFFFF`. Today, we normally use Ethernet II with IP, rather than Novell, and I have never seen Novell on iOS.